# SendUsingAccount SendAs permissions but not finding in index

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

I need to be able to send an email from VBA from a different email address. I have permissions to send from that address and can select it manually from the Outlook Message window. However, there is no index to it when I run the following code. All that shows up is my email address.

```
Sub Which_Account_Number()
'Don't forget to set a reference to Outlook in the VBA editor
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim I As Long

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    For I = 1 To OutApp.Session.Accounts.Count
        MsgBox OutApp.Session.Accounts.Item(I) & " : This is account number " & I
    Next I
End Sub
```

Is there a way to use the actual email address in the call? This is my test code for what I am trying to accomplish:

```
Sub SendMessagesTest()

   Dim objOutlook As Object ' Outlook.Application
   Dim objOutlookMsg As Object ' Outlook.MailItem
   Dim objOutlookRecip As Object ' Outlook.Recipient

    ' Create the Outlook session.
   Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
   objOutlook.Session.Logon

   ' Create the message.
   Set objOutlookMsg = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)   '0 = olMailItem              

    With objOutlookMsg

         ' Set the Subject & Body of the message.
         .Subject = "Test Subject"
         .Body = "Test Body"
         '.BodyFormat = 3   '3 = olFormatRichText  (Late Binding)

        'Change Item(1)to another number to use another account
       Set .SendUsingAccount = "TestUser@test.com" 'objOutlook.Session.Accounts.Item(2)  ' (Late Binding)

       .Display

   End With

    Set objOutlook = Nothing
    Set objOutlookMsg = Nothing
    Set objOutlookRecip = Nothing
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

When I run it I get the error "Object Required".

I cannot use this type of code because I do not have an index number to use for the email address:

```
Set .SendUsingAccount = objOutlook.Session.Accounts.Item(1)
```

Edit: This is the code that I use to add an appointment item to another user's calendars which have been shared with me. Note: I have Publishing Editor permissions on the mailbox I am trying to Send As.

```
Sub CreateCalendarApptx()
    Dim objApp As Object
    Dim objNS As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objRecip As Object
    Dim objAppt As Object
    Dim objMsg As Object
    Const olMailItem = 0
    Const olFolderCalendar = 9
    Dim strName As String

    Set objApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objNS = objApp.getNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objMsg = objApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

   strName = "OtherUser@Test.com"
    'Select Calendar on which to place the appointment
    'The Calendar can either be set with the name of the calendar or the Folder ID
    If Left(strName, 3) = "ID:" Then
        'Strip out the ID: identifier and leave just the ID
        strName = Mid(strName, 5, Len(strName))
        Set objFolder = objNS.GetFolderFromID(strName)
    Else
        Set objRecip = objMsg.Recipients.Add(strName)
        objRecip.Resolve
        If objRecip.Resolved Then
            Set objFolder = objNS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objRecip, olFolderCalendar)
        End If
    End If

    Set objAppt = objFolder.Items.Add
    objAppt.Subject = "Test"
    objAppt.Display

   Set objApp = Nothing
    Set objNS = Nothing
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objMsg = Nothing
    Set objRecip = Nothing
    Set objAppt = Nothing

End Sub
```

Edit 2:
I added another comment earlier, but the board didn't seem to like it because I attached a picture. The upshot is that when I send an email from the Outlook interface with a different name in the From: field, it sends successfully. However, when I hover over it I see "From: OtherUser@test.com   Send Using Account: Me@test.com"   If that is the case, the SendUsingAccount in VBA would be my email address, and there should be another property that would be the From: field.

Comment: Go to the File tab, you will see the "Add Account" button near the top. If you are successful there will be item 2.

Answer (score 1):

change your statement from:

```
Set .SendUsingAccount = objOutlook.Session.Accounts.Item(1)
```

to:

```
Set .SendUsingAccount = objOutlook.Session.Accounts.Item("Testuser@test.com")
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get SendUsingAccount to work -- except that items sat in the other account's Outbox and never were sent.

I finally got it to work by creating a mail profile that had the account I wanted to send as from as the only account. Then I added my mail account but left the SendUsingAccount as the default account for the profile to use. That way it continued to work.

But that's a bit inconvenient, except in my case the computer running the software is not my primary computer, so having the default profile set to a mail account other than mine will be bearable.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sending on behalf of a delegate Exchange mailbox? Set the `MailItem.SentOnBehalfOfName` property.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't want to send on behalf of, I want it to look like the email came from another user.

Comment: Have you actually tried to use the SentOnBehalfOfName property?

Comment: Yes. The email is created, but bounces back with this error: "This message could not be sent. You do not have the permission to send the message on behalf of the specified user." I assume the error is because I do not have permission to "Send On Behalf of" this user, only "Send As".

Comment: If you have send as / receive as rights, you can create a profile where that mailbox is the primary one.

Comment: I created another profile as you suggested and added the profile to the Logon line in the code above like this: objOutlook.Session.Logon "Other Profile", , True, True. It is still using my email in the from field. Can you tell me where I am missing the boat?

Comment: Was Outlook already running when your code was executed? In that case Namespace.Logon will do nothing.

Comment: That makes sense. Given that, is there a way to send from another profile in VBA when I am logged in to my own profile?

Comment: No, Outlook is a singleton - only one instance can run at a time.

Comment: So we are back to square one. How can I  send from a different account? I can do it from the Outlook interface, there must be a way to do it from VBA. I can set appointments on other people's calendars from VBA, it doesn't seem that different to me.

Comment: You can set the Sender property to an AddressEntry object.

Comment: It says on SlipStick that if you have Send As permissions and you SendOnBehalfOfName it will do a Send As. I tried that, but get the same error that I don't have permissions. For testing purposes, I gave myself permission for Send On Behalf Of and I get an error that says I don't have permission to send on behalf of the user. It gives me the same message whether I am Sending As or Sending On Behalf Of..

Comment: I am not sure about the idea of setting the Sender property to an AddressEntry object. I looked up AddressEntry object. it seems to me that it will just give me another reference that can't be resolved when I try to do a Send.

Answer (score 0):

Re: Comment to other answer post. It is unusual to do this "I can set appointments on other people's calendars from VBA".

If you have such rights, to the inbox of the other mailbox, you may be able to do this.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SendMailFromNonDefaultAccount()

    ' The only way I know this works is to
    '  use the "Add Account" button to add a non-default account.
    ' Not "Account Settings" which adds a mailbox to the default Account.

    Dim myRecipient As recipient
    Dim nonDefaultInboxFolder As Folder
    Dim addMail As MailItem

    ' This is where your unusual permission, without adding an account, might yet kick in
    Set myRecipient = Session.CreateRecipient("non-default email address as a string inside quotes")

    Set nonDefaultInboxFolder = Session.GetSharedDefaultFolder(myRecipient, olFolderInbox)

    ' Add, not create, in non-default folder
    Set addMail = nonDefaultInboxFolder.Items.Add

    ' The non-default email address will be in the "From"
    addMail.Display

End Sub
```

With the code for the shared calendar applied to the shared inbox.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateCalendarAppt_and_mail()

    Dim objApp As Object
    Dim objNS As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objRecip As Object
    Dim objAppt As Object
    Dim objMsg As Object

    Dim objInboxShared As Object
    Dim objMsgShared As Object

    ' If there is no reference to the Outlook Object Library
    Const olFolderInbox = 6

    Const olMailItem = 0
    Const olFolderCalendar = 9

    Dim strName As String

    Set objApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objNS = objApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Set objMsg = objApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    strName = "OtherUser@Test.com"
    Debug.Print strName

    Set objRecip = objMsg.Recipients.Add(strName)
    objRecip.Resolve

    If objRecip.Resolved Then

        Set objFolder = objNS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objRecip, olFolderCalendar)
        Set objAppt = objFolder.Items.Add
        objAppt.Subject = "Test"
        objAppt.Display

        ' Follows the format of the calendar code
        ' Looks the same as my original code
        Set objInboxShared = objNS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objRecip, olFolderInbox)
        ' objInboxShared.Display
        Set objMsgShared = objInboxShared.Items.Add
        objMsgShared.Subject = "Test Message"
        objMsgShared.Display

    End If

    Set objApp = Nothing
    Set objNS = Nothing
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objMsg = Nothing
    Set objRecip = Nothing
    Set objAppt = Nothing

    Set objInboxShared = Nothing
    Set objMsgShared = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I replaced the email address with the one I am wanting to use as my From: address, and then tried your code. I am getting the error "The attempted operation failed. An object could not be found." The error is being thrown on this line: Set addMail = nonDefaultInboxFolder.Items.Add

Comment: What do you get with `Debug.Print nonDefaultInboxFolder` immediately after `Set nonDefaultInboxFolder = Session.GetSharedDefaultFolder(myRecipient, olFolderInbox)`?

Comment: I get the same error when I add that line, but now it is being thrown on that line.I also tried ?nonDefaultInboxFolder in the Immediate window and get the same error.

Comment: Seems you have to figure out how to use Add Account.

Comment: I don't like using the Add Account option. When I do that it is showing me all of the reminders from his calendar and I do not need or want those. I can do this from the Outlook interface for accounts where I have Send As permissions. It just seems like I should have that same capability from VBA.

Comment: Edit the question post to show how you do this."I can set appointments on other people's calendars from VBA." Perhaps "calendar" can be change to "inbox".

Comment: I added the code I use for setting appointments on other people's calendars to the bottom of my original question.

Comment: @Kim forgot to signal you that I added code using the same format as for the calendar.

Comment: Thanks so much! I will try it tomorrow when  I am at my work computer.

Comment: I am sorry to say that the new code did not work. The email is still sending from me. One odd thing that I discovered, though, is that even  though I added the user to my accounts, which is showing me his appointment reminders, I am still unable to find an index when I run code to show all the mailboxes. The only one that shows up is mine.

Answer (score 0):

I had two machines that were experiencing this same problem.

With the first machine, the user was being prompted to select a profile on opening Outlook. By setting the Control Panel/Mail profile setting so that it "Always use this profile", the problem was fixed.

The second machone had two profiles. Even though the main one was selected to "always use this profile", it still had the same problem. By removing the second profile, the problem went away.